# HTML Required on input does not go away and form disabled

Tags: html, model-view-controller

I have text box that is in a partial and exists in a collection.
I added the required on the input box, when nothing is in the textbox and i hit submit shows field is required message and disables the form submit button.  However, then when i go type something in the text box message field is required stays and form is still disabled.

I removed the novalidateattribute on the form in case that was causing this.

Comment: can you share a snippet that demonstrate the issue ?

Comment: Cannot help without Code.